# apache metamodel -where on non-string columns in files

Tags: excel, csv, where-clause, type-conversion, apache-metamodel

I need your help,
I'm using org.apache.metamodel in order to read DataSet of files (excel, csv..),
while doing so I've noticed that all the returned columns are classified as "String", my problem is that I'm trying to filter columns values using org.apache.metamodel.query.**FilterItem**, but I see that the compare is a "String Comparison"- for example where (i<2) will return 1,10,111 etc..

I came across Data type conversion inside: "http://wiki.apache.org/metamodel/examples/DataTypeConversion"

but when i use it, it doesn't really changes the column type and my results are not correct.
**so how can i filter on non-string columns in files,**

Thanks in advance!